# How to stop Blogger overwriting your custom html?

Tags: blogger, html

Blogger overwrote my html!

Blogger replaces custom html with its own, default html, whenever a post is opened in 'compose' mode.

This means that, if you use the option to compose a post in 'html' mode, and then later go back and edit the page in 'compose' mode, Blogger overwrites your html with its own default html.

This not only means that it messes it up the way you have spaced/indented the code.

It appears to insert `<br />` breaks where there were none, and removed

blocks I had used as the main way of blocking my text elements.

If Blogger is going to offer people the option of doing their own html, shouldn't it leave that html intact once they have done it?

Worse still, Blogger seems sometimes to open a post in 'compose' mode by default when you opt to edit a post that has already been published. So if you compose a post with your own html and then go back later to edit it, Blogger opens the page in 'compose' mode, and overwrites your own html.

How do you prevent Blogger from doing this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to prevent Blogger from doing this:   the Post-editor does not support all aspects of HTML, and so some unsupported elements that you add will be removed (e.g., `<p>` tags), while others  (e.g., tables) will be kept even though there is no way to create them in Compose mode.

I do not have a list of which HTML elements are and are not supported.

The best alternative is to write your posts in Compose mode, and just use HTML mode to tweak the code, or add tables.

FYI, opening in Compose vs HTML mode is not random:   each time you edit a post, it opens in whichever mode you were last in when you edited any post from any blog  (or perhaps any post on that computer - I've not tested to confirm this).

You should also be mindful of the last item in the Options panel on the right-hand side.   It is called
Line breaks and has values of:

- Use `<br>` tag
- List item

Press "Enter" for line breaks

This may be why blocks that you thought you had entered have disappeared.

Comment: I got round the problem by simply always composing offline, in a text editor. Then create the article in 'HTML' mode in blogger and paste the whole thing in one go. Any subsequent changes can be made in the offline version and updated the same way: copy and paste the whole lot. That way, Blogger never gets the chance to overwrite your html. Sensible anyway.

Comment: "blocks that you thought you had entered" ... no, I am most sure blocks I entered were overwritten! They were overwritten and replaced with breaks. Your answer is helpful, thank you. But it does seem the only certain solution is the one I have descried in the comment above.